# XSLT passing multiple file and in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformation

I need to pass two XML files to an XSLT stylesheet for transformation.

In my XSLT, referring to one file like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="conf" select="document('Conformance.xml')"/>
```

XSL produces the required output in this case, but I want to pass this document dynamically from java.

I tried this:

```
String confSource = JAXRSConfig.marshalStr(conformance);
StringReader reader =   new StringReader(confSource);
Source ss = new StreamSource(reader);

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
transformer.setParameter("conf", ss);
transformer.transform(vpatInput, result);
```

In XSLT I referred to this doc as:

```
<xsl:param name="conf" />
<xsl:for-each select="$conf/conformance-details/section">
  <xsl:variable name="secId" select="@ids"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$conf/conformance-details/section[@ids=$secId]/criterion/remark/DeliverableName"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it's not working, any suggestions?

Comment: What is not working and in what way? What's wrong with the output, do you get any? Any Error messages somewhere?

Comment: when i directly refer the documnet like this
<xsl:variable name="conf" select="document('Conformance.xml')"/>
it's working fine, producing expected out put

but when i use 
<xsl:param name="conf" />
and set this param through transformer.setParameter("conf", ss);
it's not giving any error, the generated html table is just empty

Comment: Please add this information to your original post (explain it there in a coherent way).

Comment: Is passing values which are not Strings permitted?  The only documentation I can find is [at xml.apache.org](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/usagepatterns.html#params), which states: *Xalan-Java 2 processes string parameters.*

Comment: Expanded my answer below - it's possible using the interpreted Xalan xslt engine rather than the builtin compiled xsltc engine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the XSLT implementation that you use. The Javadoc for Transformer.setParameter says:

> @param value The value object.  This can be any valid Java object. It
>   is up to the processor to provide the proper object coersion or to
>   simply pass the object on for use in an extension.

If your processor uses a DOM tree (likely) you may try passing it either directly as a Document or Element node, or by wrapping it in a DOMSource. (My first try would be passing it directly as a Document or Element node)

.. Let me expand this answer a bit ..

Most likely, you are using a modern JVM with the built-in XSLT engine, which is the xstlc engine.
The xstlc compilation-based xslt processor doesn't support the passing of nodes or node trees through parameters, unfortunately.

However, the non-compilation based apache xalan engine does support this; I have just verified this myself using xalan-2.7.1 - it support passing a Document or Element as a parameter.

It does not support a StreamSource or as a parameter value though, so you need to serialize your configuration to a DOM tree rather than a String.

First download Xalan and required dependencies (the interpreted version of xslt is not part of the JRE library, at least not in JDK 1.7.0_17 on MacOs)

Either set to system property `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` to `org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl` or create a TransformerFactory using an implementation class name.

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl", null).
                          newTransformer(xsl);
transformer.setParameter("conf", doc);
```

There is yet another option - you could load the input document into a DOM tree, programmatically add the extra configuration document as an element to the input document, and then pass it as a DOMSource. It's a hack that I wouldn't like to use, but if you don't want to download Xalan I can't think of another option.